# How to prevent VSCode auto add new line and indent?

Tags: visual-studio-code, newline, enter, auto-indent

When I Write down a HTML tag，like :

```
···
<div></div>
···
```

And press <kbd>Enter</kbd> between `><`, VSCode always auto add new line and indent, then the result is :

```
···
<div>
    (← here have an indent)
</div>
···
```

How can I prevent VSCode operations?

Comment: Do you want to prevent BOTH the new line and the indent?

Comment: Yes, I don't need press one enter but it return two new line and some indent.

Comment: You should have the `Editor :  Auto Indent` setting with 5 options.  I think you probably want the `keep` option.   Yes, upgrade your vscode if you don't have those options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are in VSC, go to...

File > Preferences > Settings > Text Editor

Scroll down until you find:

Auto Indent and change full to **none**

*There are some operations about that you maybe want to know.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I checked the setting and found that I had previously set autoIndent to false, which is of no use. In addition, this autoIndent is a checkbox with only **on** or **off** results and no **full** or **none** option. My vscode version is 1.40.1. Is this a version problem?

Comment: Interesting, my version is 1.43.2, you could have to update your version VSC if you want, in addition, I have the extension HTML Snippets, but I think that didn't some alteration on the indent operation.

Comment: I don't want to upgrade the version for the time being. but I will try it later. Thank you again for your reply. ≖‿≖✧